# Vue3 :style backgroundImage not working with require

Tags: vue.js, binding, vuejs3, vite, bind

I'm trying to migrate a Vue 2 project to Vue 3. In Vue 2 I used v-bind style as follow:

```
<div :style="{backgroundImage: 'url('+require('/assets/imgs/'+ project.img)+')'}"></div>
```

In Vue 3 this doesn't work... I tried also:

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/assets/imgs/' + project.img)})` }"
```

Still not working.

It seems like `require` doesn't work for Vue 3, that's why I tried without it, but then I see the background-image url path in the Inspector, but the image is not there.

Can somebody help with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to use `require`

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('/src/assets/${project.img}')` }"></div>
```